# Python to js word to phonetics script

Tags: javascript, phonetics

is there a way to do this in javascript?

```
if('a' in array[index] or 'A' in array[index] ):
    print(bArray[0], end = ' ')
```

(search array for a string, return index for that string, and then `console.log(bArray[location];`)

Comment: i'm not trying to print the index, simply save it as a variable and use it for bArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```
// Convert the string to lower case so that it will match both 'a' and "A"
const aIndex = array[index].toLowerCase().indexOf('a');
if(aIndex !== -1) {
    console.log(aIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It won't let me accept answer yet, so i will asap

Comment: and may i ask why my post has been down-voted? did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest to accomplish via regex match:

```
let match = s.match(/[a]/i);
if (match) console.log(match.index, match[0]);
```

If you want a more generic version:

```
let matcher = s => {
  let regex = new RegExp(s, 'i');
  let match = s.match(regex);
  return match && [match.index, match[0]];
};
```

Comment: Regex is a bit overkill for something like this.